# Archive for Custom post type categories

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type

I created a custom post type and created custom categories for custom post type. I was able to display the posts for each custom category but not archive for each category. Please help me to get archive for each custom category

Custom Post Type - News
Category - Political

www.website.com/news/ - archive is working

www.website.com/news/political - is showing 404 error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can add Archives there by setting **has_archive** into **true**.

```
$args = array(
    'labels'             => $labels,
    'public'             => true,
    'publicly_queryable' => true,
    'show_ui'            => true,
    'show_in_menu'       => true,
    'query_var'          => true,
    'rewrite'            => array( 'slug' => 'book' ),
    'capability_type'    => 'post',
    'has_archive'        => true,
    'hierarchical'       => false,
    'menu_position'      => null,
    'supports'           => array( 'title', 'editor', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt', 'comments' )
);
```

Reference: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type

Answer (score 0):

did you have **rewrite** rule when you register your custom taxonomy?

e.g.

```
register_taxonomy( 'taxonomy_name', 
    array('post_type_name'), /* if you change the name of register_post_type( 'custom_type', then you have to change this */
    array('hierarchical' => true,     /* if this is true, it acts like categories */             
        'labels' => array(
            //blah blah blah
        ),
        'show_admin_column' => true, 
        'show_ui' => true,
        'query_var' => true,
        'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'custom-slug' ),
    )
);
```

You can try checking the actual url of your custom taxonomy slug by going to Your Post type Name (like POST) -> You Taxonomy Name (like Categories) > Hover over each title and click view,

if you still get an error page, try resetting your permalinks to default and check again,

if you still get an error page, then there's something wrong on how you register that custom category

Comment: code is same as you mentioned above. I tried with different custom slug but no use. I tried saving permalinks again. :(.

Comment: can you provide a default link of one of your custom category?

Comment: I just notice, you have a default post category news? and your custom category based url is also news? looks like slug conflict to me, did you test the default permalink?

Comment: i changed custom category slug into news-category

Comment: test the default permalink, like http://yoursite.com/?news-category=political

Comment: Thank you, i rectified the problem. i changed taxonomy name